# Compare Database Schema and Automatic UPDATE the changes from VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an application in VB.net and SQL Server 2019 database, and now is installed on on many client computers, but now in the NEW Version of the app I modify the SQL schema. For example in Table1 I added 3 new columns, in Table2 I add 1 column etc.

How can I update from VB.NET application when new app is UPDATED? **How can I compare the database schema in the clients server and my last SQL SCHEME**

I tried this but this is not good idea because I need to write many many tables and columns what I change

```
con = New SqlConnection(cs)
            '            con.Open()
            '            Dim cb2 As String = "if not exists (select *
            '               from
            '                     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
            '               where
            '                     table_name = 'Company'
            '                     and column_name = 'VersioniDB')
            '    alter table 
            '                                    Company
            'add 
            '[VersioniDB] [nchar](20) NULL"
            '            cmd = New SqlCommand(cb2)
            '            cmd.Connection = con
            '            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            '            con.Close()
```

Comment: Aren't you using SSDT?

Comment: This question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. There are many tools available to handle this. For example, from the application/service code using Entity Framework and migrations, or from the database side using tools like Redgate Deploy (or the Flyway Community edition under it) to keep database schema and data in source control and deploy changes to multiple environments.